# how to clear or disable cache in activeadmin filter select?

Tags: caching, ruby-on-rails-4, filter, activeadmin

My filter

```
filter :club_id, :label => 'Club',
         :as => :select,
         :collection => Hash[Club.order(:city_id).includes(:city).map{|d| ["#{d.city.title}, #{d.address} - #{d.title}",d.id]}]
```

When I delete or create a club, the drop-down list of select in fiter still does not change. Apparently it is cached. This occurs only in the filters. 
How do I disable this cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
 filter :club_id, as: :select, collection: proc { Hash[Club.order(:city_id).includes(:city).map{|d| ["#{d.city.title}, #{d.address} - #{d.title}",d.id]}]}
```

HTH